# Extra and false serial received data in c#

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have problem with receiving data from serial port. 12 bytes will be sent each time and I want to read each byte and put them into an array, then show them in a richtextbox (every byte will be showed in a separate line). But there is a problem: When the data is sent continuously, I get some extra 0s which are not relevant at all and which I don't receive in a terminal program. 
Here is my code, I appreciate if you could help me furhter.

```
 private void data_received(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
       richTextBox1.Invoke(new EventHandler(ReadFromPort));
    }

    private void ReadFromPort(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int bytes = 0;
        label2.Text = "";
        bytes = serialPort1.BytesToRead;
        label2.Text = bytes.ToString();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[12];

        for (int k = 0; k < bytes; k++)
        {
            buffer[k] = 0;
        }
        serialPort1.Read(buffer, 0, bytes);
        for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length  ; i++)
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText(buffer[i].ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
        }
```

}

Comment: `buffer.Length` is set to `12` when you create the array, instead of `new byte[bytes]`. Also, `new byte[]` returns a zeroed array, you don't need to set the values to zero. Also, setting the values to zero doesn't make sense because you're overwriting them in the next line.

Comment: serialPort1.Read will return the number of bytes actually read, which may be less than 12.  Your code seems to assume that it always returns 12 bytes

Comment: Yeah, that's right, because I'm sure that always 12 bytes are sent. And the terminal program confirms that as well. Now the question is why I get sometimes zeros that are not supposed to be there.

Comment: @srt the terminal may Send 12 bytes but you are reading a buffer - the buffer can contain any number of bytes.

Comment: @PhillipH with the terminal I mean another program for sending and receiving. The data is sent from another device and I have tested the receiving using this terminal program and everything was fine. Now I'm comparing the output from the terminal program and my program.

Answer (score 2):

When you [read the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143549(v=vs.110).aspx) of `SerialPort.Read`, obviously:

> Fewer bytes are read if count is greater than the number of bytes in the input buffer.

The return value indicates how much data was actually read from the port. Then display only this amount of bytes from your array:

```
int bytesRead = serialPort1.Read(buffer, 0, bytes);
for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++)
{ … }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are reading N bytes into the buffer, but displaying the whole buffer irrespective of the number of bytes you read into it. Sometimes you dont get 12 bytes, but less. But you still display all 12.

Change `for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length  ; i++)` to `for (int i = 0; i < bytes  ; i++)`